# Discord.js user.bot is not defined?

Tags: javascript, discord

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Succesfully contacted the server.');
});

client.on('message', message => {
    if (!user.bot) {
        message.delete()
           .then(message.reply('nope.'));
    }
});



client.login('Nope');
```

When I say something in discord chat I get the error in the console "ReferenceError: user is not defined."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting the error `ReferenceError: user is not defined.` because you haven't defined `user`, surprisingly enough.

```
client.on('message', message => {
    let user = message.author;
    if (!user.bot) {
        message.delete()
           .then(message.reply('nope.'));
    }
});
```